# Summing across rows of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of records that looks something like this:

```
stocks = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'], name = 'stock')
positions = pd.Series([ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500], name = 'positions')
same1 = pd.Series(['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC'], name = 'same1')
same2 = pd.Series(['AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC'], name = 'same2')
diff = pd.Series(['A1', 'A2', 'B3' ,'C1', 'C2'], name = 'different')
df = pd.DataFrame([stocks, same1, positions, same2, diff]).T
df
```

This gives a pandas DataFrame that looks like

```
      stock same1 positions same2 different
0     A    AA       100   AAA        A1
1     A    AA       200   AAA        A2
2     B    BB       300   BBB        B3
3     C    CC       400   CCC        C1
4     C    CC       500   CCC        C2
```

I'm not interested in the data in 'different' columns and want to sum the positions along the unique other columns.   I am currently doing it by:

```
df.groupby(['stock','same1','same2'])['positions'].sum()
```

which gives:

```
stock  same1  same2
A      AA     AAA      300
B      BB     BBB      300
C      CC     CCC      900
Name: positions
```

Problem is that this is a pd.Series (with Multi-Index).  Currently I iterate over it to build a DataFrame again.  I am sure that I am missing a method.   Basically I want to drop 1 column from a DataFrame and then "rebuild it" so that one column is summed and the rest of the fields (which are the same) stay in place.

This groupby method breaks if there are empty positions.   So I currently use an elaborate iteration over the DataFrame to build a new one.  Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Step 1. Use [['positions']] instead of ['positions']:

```
In [30]: df2 = df.groupby(['stock','same1','same2'])[['positions']].sum()

In [31]: df2 
Out[31]: 

                   positions
stock same1 same2               
A     AA    AAA          300 
B     BB    BBB          300 
C     CC    CCC          900
```

Step 2. And then use `reset_index` to move the index back to the column

```
In [34]: df2.reset_index()
Out[34]: 
  stock same1 same2  positions
0     A    AA   AAA        300 
1     B    BB   BBB        300 
2     C    CC   CCC        900
```

### EDIT

Seems my method is not so good.

Thanks to @Andy and @unutbu , you can achieve your goal by more elegant ways:

method 1:

```
df.groupby(['stock', 'same1', 'same2'])['positions'].sum().reset_index()
```

method 2:

```
df.groupby(['stock', 'same1', 'same2'], as_index=False)['positions'].sum()
```

Comment: Cool, so the step 1 can be ignore

Comment: If you use `df.groupby(['stock','same1','same2'], as_index=False)` then the DataFrame will preserve `['stock','same1','same2']` as columns, (thus avoiding `reset_index()` altogether.)

Comment: Thanks. It's so luck to learn a lot from answering this question.

Comment: got one problem though.   The methods break if any of the columns that are the same have NaN in them.   E.g.  

same2 = pd.Series(['AAA', 'AAA', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], name = 'same2')

replacing this in code just drop those whole rows... Think it is probably to do with the NaN == issue in pandas?

Comment: solved issue . with NaNs.   As this is mostly dat that will not be used in calculations.   did df = df.fillna('') before the method