# Efficiently handling missing dates when aggregating Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Follow up from [Summing across rows of Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17166601/2107677)  and [Pandas Dataframe object types fillna exception over different datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17173524/2107677)

One of the columns that I am aggregating using

```
df.groupby(['stock', 'same1', 'same2'], as_index=False)['positions'].sum()
```

this method is not very forgiving if there are missing data.  If there are any missing data in same1, same2, etc it pads totally unrelated values.   Workaround is to do a fillna loop over the columns to replace missing strings with ''  and missing numbers with zero solves the problem.

I do however have one column with missing dates as well.   column type is 'object'  with nan of type float and in the missing cells and datetime objects in the existing data fields.  important that I know that the data is missing, i.e. the missing indicator must survive the groupby transformation.

### Dataset outlining the problem:

csv file that I use as input is:

```
Date,Stock,Position,Expiry,same
2012/12/01,A,100,2013/06/01,AA
2012/12/01,A,200,2013/06/01,AA
2012/12/01,B,300,,BB
2012/6/01,C,400,2013/06/01,CC
2012/6/01,C,500,2013/06/01,CC
```

I then read in file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('example', parse_dates=[0])
def convert_date(d):
    '''Converts YYYY/mm/dd to datetime object'''
    if type(d) != str or len(d) != 10: return np.nan
    dd = d[8:]
    mm = d[5:7]
    YYYY = d[:4]
    return datetime.datetime(int(YYYY), int(mm), int(dd))
df['Expiry'] = df.Expiry.map(convert_date)
df
```

df looks like:

```
                 Date Stock  Position               Expiry same
0 2012-12-01 00:00:00     A       100  2013-06-01 00:00:00   AA
1 2012-12-01 00:00:00     A       200  2013-06-01 00:00:00   AA
2 2012-12-01 00:00:00     B       300                  NaN   BB
3 2012-06-01 00:00:00     C       400  2013-06-01 00:00:00   CC
4 2012-06-01 00:00:00     C       500  2013-06-01 00:00:00   CC
```

can quite easily change the convert_date function to pop anything else for missing data in Expiry column.

Then using:

```
df.groupby(['Stock', 'Expiry', 'same'] ,as_index=False)['Position'].sum()
```

to aggregate the Position column.   Get a *TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to str* with any non date that I plug into missing date data.   Important for later functionality to know if Expiry is missing.

Comment: Please could you give an example of a DataFrame where this pads unrelated values?

Comment: added data illustrating problem to question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert your dates to the `datetime64[ns]` dtype (which manages how datetimes work). An object column is not efficient nor does it deal well with datelikes. `datetime64[ns]` allow missing values using`NaT` (not-a-time), see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html#datetimes

```
In [6]: df['Expiry'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Expiry'])

# alternative way of reading in the data (in 0.11.1, as ``NaT`` will be set
# for missing values in a datelike column)
In [4]: df = pd.read_csv('example',parse_dates=['Date','Expiry'])

In [9]: df.dtypes
Out[9]: 
Date        datetime64[ns]
Stock               object
Position             int64
Expiry      datetime64[ns]
same                object
dtype: object

In [7]: df.groupby(['Stock', 'Expiry', 'same'] ,as_index=False)['Position'].sum()
Out[7]: 
  Stock              Expiry same  Position
0     A 2013-06-01 00:00:00   AA       300
1     B                 NaT   BB       300
2     C 2013-06-01 00:00:00   CC       900

In [8]: df.groupby(['Stock', 'Expiry', 'same'] ,as_index=False)['Position'].sum().dtypes
Out[8]: 
Stock               object
Expiry      datetime64[ns]
same                object
Position             int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: problem its very hard to automatically figure this out (we can but in the general case it kills perf)

Comment: Great.. One corrections though: the read_csv parser does not work if there are missing values so line[4] above fails quitly... dates coming in as text.   So I still need my munging date_formatter.   the to_datetime method is exactly what I needed.   the NaT that it creates for missing values have the desired effects.   Thanks

Comment: @Jeff not saying it should be automatic, just is a common "whoopsie". :)

Comment: @Joop, on 0.11.1 ``read_csv`` will interpret missing as ``NaT`` (this was an enhancement from 0.11.0)

Comment: @AndyHayden maybe add this type of example into ``to_datetime`` docs?

Comment: great... just a question the df.groupby statement works perfectly with missing date data now marked as NaT.   Isn't the behavior with NaNs a bug in this case?   It would be reasonable to expect the NaN to stay grouped in that case and not picking up random data from that column?

Comment: no, the problem is that you were mixing strings and floats (``np.nan``) so its undefined what it would do

Comment: sorry I meant datetimes and floats (but same result)

Comment: Sorry for discussing here.   Could I coerce the read_scv created df to for it to only Strings or floats and dates.  Guess it is the columns with object types that cause the "bad" behavior.  anything like the pd.to_datetime function to do that?

Comment: look at ``convert_objects``

Comment: cant go to 0.11.0 because of a bug in slicing reported earlier (fixed in 0.11.1 and cannot use 0.11.1 yet as I cannot use development version.   Any workarounds in 0.10.1?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32024/discussion-between-joop-and-jeff)